# Disable push notification for specific time interval iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-extensions, silentpush

Is it possible to disable (not getting/Showing) the  push notification via app. I know that, we can register or unregister for push notifications at any time, but in my application user can choose specific time-range in which he wants to get the notification.

For example: If user chooses `time-range 5-6 PM`, then app should only show the notifications between 5-6 PM, and should not show/receive/reject notification if they sent out side of the time range `time<5 and time>6`

Is it possible?
Is there any workaround with `silent-notifications`? Something like, I receive notification and can turn it into silent-notification by modifying payload via app, by using notificaiton-service-extention?

Please help!

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1

Comment: yes, I checked the documentation

Comment: @Ankush have you done this on app side ? please let me know even i have to do this. I don't know how Linkedin is doing

Answer (score 1):

You can set user time preference at your backend(Server-side), so the server send the notification to user in prefer time only.

Silent notification is not meet to your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I knew that this is one option. I was thinking not to modify the backend. But anyway, Thanks for clarifying this issue